# ForEach through multiple TextField to verify if empty or not in SwiftUI

Tags: foreach, swiftui, textfield, disable

I'm having a little trouble figuring out how I can check if the text is empty in each of my text fields. I have 3 sections of text fields all in a VStack, I only need user input from 2/3 of the sections (variables I guess) you see below.

How can I check which two sections the user inputed text and have the final results in the section the textfield(s) were left empty? I've already put all my TextField String variables into a lazy var.

Now I know I need forEach to accomplish this or even For In would be more preferred.

Thank you in advance!

Hopefully I explained it well and can see this being feasible in the future to others such as greying out the textfield that was left empty out of the 2/3 sections. That's just one example but appreciate it!

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @fuzz I've put all my textfields into a array then this "let theArr = self.array.allSatisfy { $0.isEmpty }" but I can't use it for some reason. I get a mutable error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may update based on the following:

```
 @State var array = [String](repeating: "", count: 3)
 @State var array1 = [String](repeating: "", count: 1)
 @State var array2 = [String](repeating: "", count: 3)
 @State  var var1 = true
 @State  var var2 = true
 @State  var var3 = true


  var body: some View{
  VStack {
    HStack{ TextField("text0", text: $array[0])
            TextField("text0", text: $array[1])
            TextField("text0", text: $array[2])
    }.onReceive(array.publisher) { _ in

        self.var1 = self.array.allSatisfy{$0.isEmpty}
        self.check()
      }
    HStack{
       TextField("text1", text: $array1[0])
    }.onReceive(array1.publisher) { _ in

        self.var2 = self.array1.allSatisfy{$0.isEmpty}
        self.check()
      }
    HStack{
      TextField("text2", text: $array2[0])
      TextField("text2", text: $array2[1])
       TextField("text2", text: $array2[2])
    }.onReceive(array2.publisher) { _ in

        self.var3 = self.array2.allSatisfy{$0.isEmpty}
        self.check()
      }
   }
  }

 func check(){

    switch ( (var1 ? 1 : 0) | (var2 ? 2: 0) | (var3 ? 4:0)){
        case 0b001: print( "var1", var1)
        case 0b010: print( "var2", var2)
        case 0b100: print( "var3", var3)
        default: return
        }
    }

   }
```

Comment: How would this tell me which field is empty? I'll have a button that will do the checking. I just want the user to fill any 2 sections out of the 3 sections and have the results after the math show up on the field the user left empty based off the first 2 sections information.

Comment: Any idea? I'm not too sure with this one. I may have to do it differently

Comment: You may add a `check` function to find out which one is empty.

Comment: I tried to do an if statement to check all the variables provided but didn't work. I feel like I'm overthinking this, this is the toughest one out of my whole app and the last one. Really trying to top it off. Thank you!

Comment: I did add a check for you

Comment: Just out of curiosity and wanting to understand, I get most of the code but what does "(var1 ? 1 : 0)" mean? I know | means to compare against each other

Comment: Just one way to convert Bool to Integer.

Comment: How can I reset all the array results to reuse again? Right now I open and close the view. I have a button that calls the self.check()

Comment: Just reset all array values and all vars

Comment: I did “self.array.removeAll()” but it doesn’t clear the textfields. I also need to do something with vars? Example? Thanks man you been a good dude through all this.

Comment: Set them to the initial values in the top of the codes.

Comment: The original values would be 0 until the user presses a button then it goes to the case above that you showed me. I'm not sure what you mean, wouldn't removeAll work then cause that's how it is originally when you open the page. I'm not really understanding

Comment: For each array, set it to the original value which is not an empty array. for example :  array = [String](repeating: "", count: 3)